# Install Windows to a Nvme ssd disk that is not recognized by BIOS

Tags: bios, windows-installation, nvme

I have a Nvme ssd disk that my computer's BIOS does not recognize and a simple bootable ssd.
I want to install Windows 10 on nvme but the bootloader to the other bootable ssd. Windows recognized the Nvme but as it is not-botable I cannot reboot while the installer want to do that.
Is there a workaround for this?
I tried to clone an existing Windows 10 partition to this nvme disk, trying to put its bootloader to the bootable ssd but failed. (winload.efi missing or corrupt)
Does anybody have solution for this problem?

Comment: I don't think this will work. the UEFI NVMe driver is required to access NVMe drives not only for boot loader but up to a certain point of the boot process where the Windows NVMe driver takes over. So without NVMe access you cant load the Windows NVMe driver, thus Windows can not take over. You should use a SATA SSD as boot and Windows drive.